# Change element text but leave inner span (or add span back) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown where the user selects "Past", "This", or "Next".

```
<div class="btn-group dropup three" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="TPN" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  This
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu fullwidth">
    <li><a onclick="setPast()">Past</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="setThis()">This</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="setNext()">Next</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

When an option is clicked it calls the appropriate function to change the text open the button. Example:

```
function setPast(){
   $('#TPN').text("Past");
}
```

However, this function strips away the span tag

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

I can not figure out how to add this span. I have tried:

```
$('#TPN').append("<span class="caret"></span>");
```

and

```
$("TNP").text('new-text').append($('<span></span>').addClass('caret'));
```

How can I add this span, or better yet, what can I do to keep it from being removed in the first place?

Comment: you have put TNP not TPN `$("TNP").text('new-text').append($('<span></span>').addClass('caret'));`

Comment: Or just use the ID  on the Span tag instead :)

Comment: Great spot, but this was just a stackoverflow typo. Unfortunately that does not solve my problem.

Comment: Philip, I need to use the id on the button tag, it should contain [This, Past, Next] and then the span tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put text in another span.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="TPN" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="text">This</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udzztobp/2/

Answer (score 2):

alternatively to the answer above, if you want to add the caret back in, change:

```
$('#TPN').append("<span class="caret"></span>");
```

to this:

```
$('#TPN').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have very tight control over what the text is (specifically you know that text will never include other HTML), you can always just use regex and an [`.html()` replacer function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

```
$('#TPN').html(function(i, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/^[^<]+/, 'new text');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I need to add: with plain JS, you can very, very easily do this without re-setting the span afterwards or modifying the HTML: `elem.childNodes` accesses *text nodes* [as well].

```
var elem = document.getElementById('TPN');
elem.childNodes[0].textContent = 'Past';
```

As for the dropdown menu, you could simplify:

```
function setText(e) {
  var target = e.target,
      txtNode = document.getElementById('TPN').childNodes[0];
  if (target.nodeName === 'A')
    txtNode.textContent = target.textContent;
}

var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0];
menu.addEventListener('click', setText, false);
```

And in HTML simply have:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu fullwidth">
    <li><a>Past</a></li>
    <li><a>This</a></li>
    <li><a>Next</a></li>
</ul>
```